# show that the set of numbers in $(0, 1)$ that have a decimal expansion with one hundred consecutive 4s is a Borel set and find its Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I have solved the following problem and I would like to know if my proof is correct and/or if it could be improved, thanks.

"show that the set of numbers in $(0, 1)$ that have a decimal expansion with one hundred consecutive 4s is a Borel set and find its Lebesgue measure"

My proof:

Let $E:=\{x\in (0,1):x\text{ has as decimal expansion with one hundred consecutive }4\text{s}\}$ and define (note that, for example, $0.\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5=0.\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}99999\dots$):

$E_0=[0.\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}, 0.\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5]$,

$E_1=\bigcup_{n_1\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}}[0.n_1\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}, 0.n_1\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5]$

$E_2=\bigcup_{n_1,n_2\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}}[0.n_1n_2\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}, 0.n_1n_2\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5]$

$E_3=\bigcup_{n_1,n_2,n_3\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}}[0.n_1n_2n_3\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}, 0.n_1n_2n_3\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5]$

$\vdots$

$E_k=\bigcup_{n_1,n_2,\dots, n_k\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}}[0.n_1n_2\dots n_k\underbrace{44\dots4}_{100}, 0.n_1n_2\dots n_k\underbrace{44\dots4}_{99}5]\  \dots$;

now, closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are Borel sets and each $E_j$ is the union of such intervals so the $E_j$s are Borel sets too and since $E=\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}E_k$ we can conclude that $E$ is a Borel set.

---

To determine the Lebesgue measure of $E$ represent the numbers in base $10^{100}$: then we may envision $(0,1)$ as a segment divided into $10^{100}$ smaller segments of length $\frac{1}{10^{100}}$. Of these sub-segments the $\underbrace{444\dots 44}_{100}$th one must be taken, since it represent numbers in $(0,1)$ whose decimal expansion begins with one hundred $4$s. Each one of the remaining $10^{100}-1$ sub-segments can be divided into $10^{100}$ sub-segments, each of length $(\frac{1}{10^{100}})^2$ and of these, as before, we have to take the $\underbrace{444\dots 44}_{100}$th one, because it contains a run of one hundred $4$s and continuing in this fashion we have that $\mu(E) =1\cdot\frac{1}{10^{100}}+ (10^{100}-1)\cdot (\frac{1}{10^{100}})^2+(10^{100}-1)^2 (\frac{1}{10^{100}})^3+\dots +(10^{100}-1)^k (\frac{1}{10^{100}})^{k+1} +\dots =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}+(10^{100}-1)^k (\frac{1}{10^{100}})^{k+1} =\frac{1}{10^{100}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-\frac{1}{100})^k=\frac{1}{10^{100}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-(1-\frac{1}{100})}=\frac{1}{10^{100}}\cdot 10^{100}=1.\ \square$

Comment: Why the minuses when you're in $(0,1)$? But your proof is correct. However, you should close the intervals on the right with $)$ instead of $]$.

Comment: I would understand the set to be all real numbers with _at least_ one sequence of _at least_ 100 consecutive 4’s.

Comment: Ek is the union of 0.9 x 10^k intervals of length 10^-100-k and therefore has measure 0.9 x 10^-100.  So your sum seems quite wrong to me. I’d bet that the measure is 1. If you take a subset, the base 10^100 numbers where any of the base 10^100 digits is 100 4’s, that will have measure 1.

Comment: None of your sets contains $0.\underbrace{444...4}_{101}$ (with 101 fours).

Comment: @tomasz I don't think that's correct.  If a number has $101$ $4$'s starting at position $k+1$ it's in the interval $E_k$.   Well, it would if $E_k$ were closed on the right, instead of open to allow for nothing but $4$'s.

Comment: I don't see that $E_i\cap E_j=\emptyset$  Suppose the first $100$ positions of $x$ are $4$s and positions $300$ through $399$ are also $4$s.  Isn't $x\in E_{100}\cap E_{299}$?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, you are right, thanks

Comment: Your proposed proof that it's a Borel set is definitely on the right track. I haven't looked closely enough to be sure it's entirely right. Your computation of the measure of the set seems to need some refinement.

Comment: @gnasher729 I posted an answer giving essentially the solution you outlined in a comment, because it didn't seem like you were going to post one.  If you post an answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @amsmath thank you for your interest in my question; I have edited by proof deleting the negative part but I think I should still use a square bracket on the right since, for example, $0.\underbrace{444\dots 4}_{99}5=0.\underbrace{444\dots 4}_{100}999\dots 999\dots$